# Hpw to show Flink metrics with JMX reporter on Local from Jconsole JMX console

Tags: jboss, yaml, wildfly, jmx, apache-flink

I am learning all these. Please share your ideas and help.

I am trying to see flink metrics with JMX reporter from JMX console. Steps:

1. I have Apache-flink installed by homebrew, alias `fstart` and `fstop` for starting/stopping Flink. Based on [this JMX reporter link][https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/monitoring/metrics.html#jmx-orgapacheflinkmetricsjmxjmxreporter], I added below 3 lines at the end of flink-conf.yaml

   `metrics.reporters: jmx
   metrics.reporter.jmx.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.jmx.JMXReporter
   metrics.reporter.jmx.port: 8789`
2. I downloaded Wildfly (JBoss application server), from its bin folder, run JConsole.sh.
3. The Jconsole shows local processes. I picked `"org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager"` and `Connect`. 
   [JConsole - available processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJbHQ.png) . It shows the default Beans [Default beans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JgFp.png). However, no Flink related beans appears here.

Correct me if I am wrong please. I assume if Flink metrics through JMX reporter is sending metrics to my local JMX box, then I should be able to see any of below metrics from the beans.  https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/monitoring/metrics.html#system-metrics

What step have I done wrong or missing please? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to a remote process via `localhost:8789`?

Comment: @DawidWysakowicz yes, it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you explicitly configure a port you have to connect to JMX using this port. If you omit the port the metrics will be available when connecting locally.

The documentation is a bit contradictory in that regard "If this setting is set Flink will start an extra JMX connector for the given port/range. Metrics are always available on the default local JMX interface."

Comment: Thank you. also @DawidWysakowicz . localhost is remoting host, connect with the configed port number 8789 worked. Thanks.